# Optimizing conditional code inside nested for-loops

Tags: java, for-loop, optimization, nested-loops

Let's say I have some code that looks something like below.

```
boolean changecode = 0;

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    //some code
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        //some more code
        if (changecode) {
            //Code A
        } else {
            //Code B
        }
    }
}
```

This code would run the if-condition every time the loops were run, ending up executing it 16 times, which isn't really optimized. Now, I could of course do this:

```
boolean changecode = 0;

if (changecode) { 
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        //some code
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            //some more code
            //Code A
        }
    }
} else {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        //some code
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            //some more code
            //Code B
        }
    }
}
```

But i suppose this isn't really optimized either, thinking about all the repetition of code. Is there a way to make the conditional run in the outer layer and replace what code should be ran in the middle of the nested for-loop?

Comment: In your first code, the testing of a boolean being true would be very fast.

Comment: Expanding on what @ScaryWombat said, if the conditional does some complex computation, hoist the result of that out into a `boolean` on top, but leave the `if` (which is now very cheap -- and maybe JITable) inside the (non-duplicated) loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case I would say it is pretty much the same. I would always go for the cleaner code over optimization (because it will be close to none if not none). The compiler will optimize/cache the result probably and even if it tests a boolean it is an operation that doesn't add performance loss. And longer code does ;) Also you can use an interface and some OOP pattern to avoid the repetition and the if/else. But it will add extra objects probably so just use the first option.

Answer (score 2):

I think the compiler will be able to optimize this away, but for the question's sake, you could do

```
Runnable code = changecode 
                   ? () -> codeA() 
                   : () -> codeB();
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    //some code
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        //some more code
        code.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the question seems to be about micro-optimizations, introducing an extra method call is maybe not the way forward (unless the compiler can remove it again)

Comment: @Thilo afaik, method calls at this point are dirty cheap which means that it might still be faster than doing 16 conditional checks... hard to tell at such micro level

Comment: @Sarief A method call is not going to be faster than checking an effectively-final `boolean` local variable (and also more difficult for an optimizer to reason about for further transformations)

Comment: It's nice but for readability its better to make these methods. Otherwise the code will be very hard to read with anonymous pieces of code

Comment: I upvoted the solution but just a little test (I am not sure if it is correct) showed that with two loops up to MaxInt and empty methods using functional interface takes 1900ms (consistent) and using if statement inside the for loop takes 1200ms. I am not saying it is 100% correct but still if we are talking for optimization this should be taken into account

Comment: @Thilo nvm, I was thinking of calling method once instead of calling 16 checks. not calling method 16 times

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, boolean comparison is very cheap performance-wise. It is not worth optimizing something like this just to make the code look worse.

In my opinion it is very important not to overthink small things like this. Don't optimize it unless you see some performance problems and there is nothing else to improve.

It is worth mentioning that very often the compiler will optimize it on its own, there is no need to bother. Btw. it might be worth checking this article about dumb code: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html